# Create Windows Desktop widget which connects to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, windows-7, windows-desktop-gadgets

I want to create a desktop widget for Windows 7.

My requirements are below

1. I can provide SQL Server login credentials
2. It should connect to SQL Server
3. List out all the jobs in the server

Can anyone guide me on how to do this and where to start from?

Comment: What programming language are you going to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps create a middle layer, that returns XML/JSON/HTML/..., that your widget can call through HTTP?

SQL Server 2005 supported native XML web services using [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)/HTTP endpoints.
It's been deprecated in sql server 2008.

Your best bet would be to create a small HTTP server that acts as a broker between your SQL Server and desktop widgets.
You can find C# example code for HTTP server on Google.
http://www.google.is/search?hl=is&q=c%23+simple+http+server

Then let your widget just call the HTTP server for the information you want to display.

PS: Make your HTTP server log on and talk to the SQL Server, don't send database credentials (or ay other for that matter) over HTTP.